# Count table field values in certain section

Tags: sections, table-field, count

I would like to know, how many values are saved in the table field called "artikelnummer" with the field name "artikel". The section is called "bikes". I tried:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('bikes') %}

{% for entry in entries %}
  {% for row in entry.artikelnummer %}
    {{ row.artikel|length }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `{{ row.length }}` gives me Key "length" for array with keys "col1, artikel" does not exist error. {{entry.artikelnummer|length}} gives me: 2 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 1 0 1 1 2. I need the sum of them.

Comment: sorry, misread your question. updated the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the total amount of rows like this:

```
{% set totalcount = 0 %}
{% for entry in entries %}
    {% set totalcount = totalcount + entry.artikelnummer|length %} 
{% endfor %}
```

**Edit**

In the loop you add the length to the totalCount.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Had to add a `{% set totalcount = 0 %}` outside the loop and it worked!

Comment: @TomS I'll edit the answer so it's more clear for everyone ;)